# Open a file and copy its contents into another file

Tags: php, file-io

In this example, the contents of the style.css file are not being written to the output string. What am I doing wrong?

```
$openFile = get_theme_root() . "/" . get_template() . "/myfile.css";
$customcss = fopen($openFile, 'w');
$customcss.=file_get_contents(get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/styles/test/style.css");
fwrite($openFile, $customcss);
fclose($openFile);
```

Comment: why not use file_put_contents instead of fopen, fwrite, fclose?

Comment: Why not just [`copy`](http://php.net/copy) the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following error:

At the line 2, you put a resource in `$customcss` (according to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)). Then you tried to append a string to it (line 3) which is a non-sense. So, just change the var at line 2.

Comment: Thanks, I believe file_put_contents is what I'm looking for.